# Parsing multiple xsd files in java

Tags: java, xml-parsing, xsd

I am working on a module to generate dynamic form by reading xsd files. For that first i need to find all the required/optional elements along with their field restriction and data type.In the Schema there can be elements which can refer to other xsd files. I am not sure how to handle this scenario. Till now I am able to fetch simple type elements from the xsd files however I am not able to figure out a way to handle cases when xsd can have complex element referring a different xsd files. below is the xsd file i am working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://edd.att.com/cnmeddservice" targetNamespace="http://edd.att.com/cnmeddservice" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="EDD_DataTypes.xsd"/>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="EDD_Internal_DataTypes.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="RET_MAIL">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Represents the eddbdsbatch request for RET_MAIL</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="AccountNumber">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="15"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="cType">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="CtypeType">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="RET_MAIL"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="RequestId">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
                            <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{1,9}"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BillingId" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="12"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BillingRegion" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="S"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="P"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="B"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="A"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="N"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="W"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BillIndicator" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="LS"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="EmailAddress" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="75"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="AccountBalance" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="DecimalAmountType">
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="BillAmount" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="DecimalAmountType">
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="DateLastchecked" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:pattern value="((0[1-9]|1[012])/(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(19|20)\d\d) ((0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="PaymentDueDate" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="DateType"/>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="ctn">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="ContactNumberType">
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="AlternateCTN" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="10"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="AltPhoneExtension" minOccurs="0">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:maxLength value="4"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
                <xsd:element name="CustomerType">
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                            <xsd:enumeration value="R"/>
                            <xsd:enumeration value="B"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="clientIndicator" use="required">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="ClientIndicatorType">
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Wireless_BDS"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="OverridePriorityString" use="optional">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:enumeration value="E"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="A"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="S"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
            <xsd:attribute name="Languageid" use="optional">
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:enumeration value="EN"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="ES"/>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:attribute>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

as in the above xsd i have included two different xsds files ( EDD_INTERNAL_DATATYPES and EDD_DATATYPES). Now suppose i have and element which can be a table with 2-3 elements . Now in my main xsd files i will have my table name and the reference of the column name i will give in the secondry xsd files I have included. **SO my question is how can i fetch the column name from xsds i have included .**

Answer (score 0):

> SO my question is how can i fetch the column name from xsds i have
>   included.

You'll need to read and process the included XSDs the same way you read and processed the root XSD, and you'll need to do so recursively because the included XSDs may also include additional XSDs.

However, I'd suggest that you assess the magnitude of work involved in supporting all possible constructs in XSD in your forms endeavor.  In addition to `xsd:include`, realize that an arbitrary XSDs might also use:

- `xsd:import`
- `xsd:extension` / `xsd:restriction`
- `substitutionGroup`
- Etc.

Perhaps you're already handling those, but to question the handling of the relatively simple `xsd:include` statement suggests that perhaps greater complexity awaits you.

Two suggestions:

1. Narrow scope by supporting only a subset of XML Schema.
2. Consult some battle-hardened source such as that of Xerces-J 2 for
   guidance on processing the many esoteric statements in XML Schema.

Finally, be aware of other forms efforts in XML such as [XForms](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/Forms/#waXForms) and [XFA](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/xml/index_arch.html).